# Why is `io.BytesIO` not a `io.BufferedRandom` implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this an intentional design decision or more like a design oversight, since `BytesIO` could provide this (useful) functionality without any overhead at all.

So my question is whether there is a specific rationale for this design.

Comment: It is, though? On my Python 2.7 and 3.5 an instance of `BytesIO` has both `seek` and `tell`. It doesn’t have `peek`, though, which is a shame.

Comment: Ah, `BytesIO` can be simply wrapped in `io.BufferedReader`, which will provide a `peek` as well (but at a cost of another buffer, I guess).

Answer (score -1):

Well what I know from the documentation :

**io.BytesIO inherits BufferedIOBase** .

And also provides an additional method

```
getbuffer()
Return a readable and writable view over the contents of the buffer without copying them. Also, mutating the view will transparently update the contents of the buffer:
```

**io.BufferedRandom() inherits BufferedReader/Writer which in turn inherits BuffereIOBase**

So in totality it  provides four extra methods.

2 from BufferedReader/Writer :

```
peek([n])
Return bytes from the stream without advancing the position. At most one single read on the raw stream is done to satisfy the call. The number of bytes returned may be less or more than requested.

read([n])
Read and return n bytes, or if n is not given or negative, until EOF or if the read call would block in non-blocking mode.
```

2 additionally implemented are

```
 seek() 
 tell()
```

Comment: The question is about *why* they designed it this way, not which way it is (which is stated in the question).

Comment: @dom0 I think the stated the reason implicitly . that extra methods have been added in the child packages . This can be more sort of a modularization decision. Well if you know I am happy to learn